# How to represent multiple types (union types) when targeting JavaScript

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

What I would like to do is use a generic type that can be one of three other types.

Here's an example with a function:

```
fun <T> get(key: String) : T where T: String, T: Number, T: Boolean {}
```

The above code doesn't work, so how should I go about doing this?

Comment: @JaysonMinard Yes that's correct. I'm translating some Typescript definition files that have union types over to Kotlin, which is why I'd like to do it. Although the below answers are good, they don't fit into what I need. So I'll just have to use the `Any` type for now.

Comment: I made the question clear about your use case, and added an answer focused on the TypeScript / JS target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For KotlinJS you can use [ts2kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt) to translate your TypeScript definitions to Kotlin.  It does support Union Types but maybe not all cases are perfect.  There are [tests for unionTypes in ts2kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt/tree/master/testData/unionType) that shed light on how they are handled now and you can do something similar for anything you are creating by hand when targetting the JavaScript platform.

Further work is mentioned in comments to [issue #41 - to add better Union Type support](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt/issues/41).  Lastly there is at least one [discussion thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-will-kotlin-handle-union-types-from-javascript-typescript/1799) on the topic that indicates:

> In JS and TS in most cases union types used as the alternative to overloading, so in the near future, we going to use overloading for that when it possible.
>   Also,​ we think about providing the additional way to specify union types for native declarations.

There is another Stack Overflow question talking about this and gives a few current options:  [Kotlin and discriminated unions (sum types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695254/kotlin-and-discriminated-unions-sum-types) which has answers that are valid across all Kotlin target platforms.

Specifically for the JavaScript target you can consider using the [`dynamic` type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html).  I see at least [one test case in ts2kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt/blob/master/testData/unionType/aliases.d.kt#L4) that is using this type.  This example starts with this TypeScript code:

```js
declare class Foo

type Key = Key2 | number;
type Key2 = string | Foo;
declare var fooKey: Key;

declare function barKey(a: Key|number);
declare function barList(a: List<Key>);
declare function barArray(a: Key[]);

interface Parent {
    (...children: Key[]): Foo;
}
```

And generates this Kotlin using `dynamic` as a return type in place of the union type; and in other cases overloading the method signature to handle the union type (*some comments added by me*):

```
external open class Foo

// using dynamic in place of union type
external var fooKey: dynamic /* String | Foo | Number */ = definedExternally

// using method overloading in place of union type
external fun barKey(a: String): Unit = definedExternally
external fun barKey(a: Foo): Unit = definedExternally
external fun barKey(a: Number): Unit = definedExternally

// using dynamic in place of union type
external fun barList(a: List<dynamic /* String | Foo | Number */>): Unit = definedExternally
external fun barArray(a: Array<dynamic /* String | Foo | Number */>): Unit = definedExternally

external interface Parent {
    // using method overloading in place of union type
    @nativeInvoke
    fun invoke(vararg children: String): Foo
    @nativeInvoke
    fun invoke(vararg children: Foo): Foo
    @nativeInvoke
    fun invoke(vararg children: Number): Foo
}
```

But again, you should review all of the [ts2kt test cases for union types](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt/tree/master/testData/unionType) to see other ideas *including for handling of `undefined`*.

Answer (score 9):

This does not work because `T` cannot be represented as some type that is at the intersection of `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean`.

If you want to restrict your type to a list of predefined types, sealed classes are a great soltuion.

```
sealed class MyData {
  class Bool(val data: Boolean) : MyData()
  class String(val data: String) : MyData()
  class Number(val data: Number) : MyData()
}

fun get(key: String): MyData = TODO()
```

Answer (score 1):

How would the compiler know what type is being returned in this case? `T` could presumably be anything, so they would be no way to define something like that.

You could define three type-specific methods:

```
fun getString(key: String): String = ...
fun getBoolean(key: String): Boolean= ...
fun getInt(key: String): Int = ...
```

(Or a wrapper method, as kevinmost suggested)